# How to use collapse_key with GCM and Phonegap PushPlugin

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, google-cloud-messaging

I'm able to send GCM notifications with payload by using PushPlugin for Phonegap. However what I need is only a send-to-sync message. From what I read and understand, messages without a payload and with a collapse_key would be the way to go. However, I couldn't figure out how to implement and use that with PushPlugin.

If I don't change the plugin's code, I'm able to get the property message, in the device, with  the payload. I was expecting not to use that property and to be able to get a property collapse_key in the device, but looks like it doesn't work that way or is not implemented for PushPlugin.

Am I right or there's another way to go?

Thank you.